# Why does `Iterator.find()` require a mutable `self` reference?

Tags: iterator, rust

From [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.find):

```
fn find<P>(&mut self, predicate: P) -> Option<Self::Item> 
where P: FnMut(&Self::Item) -> bool
```

I don't see why it needs a mutable ref to `self`. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It needs to be able to mutate `self` because it is advancing the iterator. Each time you call `next`, the iterator is mutated:

```
fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item>;
```

Here is [the implementation of `find`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.4.0/src/libcore/iter.rs):

```
fn find<P>(&mut self, mut predicate: P) -> Option<Self::Item> where
    Self: Sized,
    P: FnMut(&Self::Item) -> bool,
{
    for x in self.by_ref() {
        if predicate(&x) { return Some(x) }
    }
    None
}
```